# Eliminating mains hum from frequency modulated RF LC oscillators

Tags: rf, noise, oscillator

I'm trying to build a frequency modulated LC oscillator but all circuits I've tried have terrible mains hum after demodultaion.

The oscillator is tuned by capacitive sensor but I'm using a fixed capacitor instead until I solve this problem. I've tried different topologies: Franklin, Clapp, Vackář, Hartley at different frequencies from 60 to 500 MHz but there's no difference between them in terms of mains hum. I'm using an SDR receiver for demodulation, it works fine and cannot be the source of hum. Using battery instead of AC supply didn't help. I`m using 10 µF and 10 nF capacitors for decoupling. Using physically smaller inductors helped a little, but the noise is still unacceptable.

As suggested in comments, I've tested all circuit nodes with and without powering the circuit and 50 Hz component appears only at the antenna output.

Here are some PCB drawings, maybe there are mistakes in routing?

Fig. 1: Vackář topology, the transistor is BF545C
[image]

Fig. 2: Franklin topology, both transistors are ATF-38143
[image]

[UPD:]

Uploading my setup and schematics as requested. The setup is just an SDR receiver and the oscillator with a piece of wire at the output as a makeshift antenna. The capacitive sensor C<sub>var</sub> is absent, as I'm using a fixed capacitor C<sub>4</sub> instead.

Fig. 3a:
 [image]

Fig. 3b:
 [image]

Fig. 3c:
 [image]

[UPD2:]

SNR at 50 Hz is 4.3 dB. Maximum frequency deviation for Franklin oscillator is 290 kHz, output power is 7.8 dBm, received signal level is –26 dBFS. Grounding the laptop makes no difference.

[UPD3:]

I've made a new board with a ground plane and a nickel silver EMI shield. I've added a 1.8V LD1117 regulator and 100pF and 390pF NP0 decoupling capacitors — and still no luck. There are no significant changes in the noise performance. Unfortunately, I couldn't find an iron box to put the whole circuit in, but I'm almost sure there are some clever circuit and PCB design techniques that do not require magnetic shielding. For example, I've tested the SDR receiver on a cheap unshielded FM transmitter: there's no hum at all, even with the volume maxed out, so the culprit is definitely the circuit and PCB design.

Here are some photos of the board (sorry for the flux, I did try to remove it but failed)

Fig. 4a:
[image]

Fig. 4b:
[image]

Fig. 4c:
[image]

Also, as suggested in the answer below, I've recorded an IF from my SDR receiver and generated its spectrum at low frequencies.

Fig. 5a: Without the EMI shield
[image]

Fig. 5b: With the EMI shield
[image]

[UPD4:]

Now that is interesting.

Increasing C<sub>4</sub> (see Fig. 3c) reduces the noise significantly. Look at the demodulated signal spectrums (the 440 Hz component is a test signal recorded from the sensor for SNR measurement):

Fig. 6a: C<sub>4</sub> = 1.5 pF
[image]

Fig. 6b: C<sub>4</sub> = 2.7 pF
[image]

Unfortunately, I've got no other capacitors in the range between 1 and 10 pF to make further tests (the oscillator won't start with C<sub>4</sub> ≥ 10 pF). I guess that the AC line noise picked by PCB traces and L<sub>2</sub> changes the gate capacitance of J<sub>1</sub>, and increasing the value of C<sub>4</sub> reduces the influence of those changes on frequency. This is also confirmed by adding a strong noise source, e.g. a cell phone making a call. You can see large spikes on Fig. 6c and the frequency does actually increase when I add a noise source, meaning that the gate capacitance of J<sub>1</sub> is inversely proportional to voltage. Makes sense to me. Seems like I need to either reduce coupling between J<sub>1</sub> and LC tank or add some high-pass filtering between them, but I'm not sure what the best way of doing it is.

Fig. 6c:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried probing the input signal for hum?

Comment: "*Using battery instead of AC supply didn`t[sic] help*", this should tell you something.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I used to employ a capacitive sensor as input and replacing it with fixed capacitor doesn`t help. There is no input signal as of now.

Comment: @HarrySvensson maybe it better should, but it doesn\`t, unfortunately. I\`m at my wit\`s end.

Comment: This question boils down to "Locate the source of the humming from the mains", the "schematics" doesn't tell me much, and you **have** ruled out the source by using a battery. The only thing that remains are actual images of your setup, or proper schematics, but I doubt that schematics alone will give the entire story. - The things that smell fishy are Fish#1: "*The oscillator is tuned by **capacitive sensor***", I don't know how that looks like. You do. Share that information with us. - Fish #2: Have you tried measuring different nodes in your... "filter" for the mains frequency?

Comment: And for the future, seeing ` being used as ' is like [hearing someone call coolwhip for coolHwip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZmqJQ-nc_s). I won't be the last one to tell you this. - If I did something *strange* in a public domain without knowing it, then I'd appreciate if someone told me. This is me being that someone for you.

Comment: PCB layout looks OK. Look elsewhere. How are you coupling this oscillator into SDR?

Comment: @HarrySvensson [F#1] with the capacitive sensor swapped for the fixed capacitor (Cvar → C4, see the question update) the problem persists, so apparently it isn\`t the culprit. [F#2] Checked all nodes with my oscilloscope (RIGOL DS 1052E). No visible noise found.

Comment: I'm no antenna theorist, so I'm out on deep waters right now, but I do know how to *debug* things. - You read mains while being encapsulated by mains cables (you're indoors), it's not that *super* weird. With this said, do you still read mains signal even when the bench supply is off (not sending any data)? - This will probably be my last comment since I'm pretty unfit for this question. Just getting as much information as I can so when the proper antenna users come along, they will say "Hah! His flux capacitor is broken, look at that Marty, he won't be able to go back to the future!".

Comment: Mains hum, if the circuit is battery-powered, can only come from injected magnetic or electric fields. Or the circuit is oscillating at some frequency that looks like mains 50/60Hz.

Comment: Pls include details in question: Test setup and measurement results. (RF: sideband deltaF, dB, AM?, FM?) (demod: SNR 50Hz)  Then test with laptop earth grounded.

Comment: I had some experience with power circuits "buzzing", the cause was found to be the ceramic capacitors used.

Comment: You can experiment with replacing the existing ceramic caps with other ceramic caps and if the noise signature changes this could confirm the cause. a solution to the problem might be replacing with "higher" quality ceramic caps or using polyester/electrolytic/mica capacitors.

Comment: Some solutions for noisy ceramic caps: https://www.edn.com/design/components-and-packaging/4364020/Reduce-acoustic-noise-from-capacitors

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Updated the post. Modulation and test setup were already included (FM; oscillator + SDR receiver)

Comment: @Gomunkul I will try new capacitors as soon as I receive them though I doubt that this will help, because I`m using high quality Vishay VJ series high-rel RF C0G capacitors and Murata GQM series high Q capacitors.

Comment: WHat is the deviation of carrier due to 50Hz?  You said "SNR at 50 Hz is 4.3 dB. Maximum frequency deviation for Franklin oscillator is 290 kHz"    I presume there is no AM on carrier, just FM

Comment: "50 Hz component appears at antenna"  ???? Is this baseband, AM, FM or PM???

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Well, it\`s hard for me to tell, because my oscilloscope bandwidth is only 50 MHz and the signal frequency is 400 MHz, so I can\`t see the waveform. When I probe the output with oscilloscope, I see a baseband 50 Hz (+ harmonics) 200mVpp component. When demodulating, I hear the hum regardless of demodulation type, FM or AM. Here\`s the signal spectrum from SDR receiver, maybe it will tell you something: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA0ss.jpg

Comment: With a circuit of this type, I am not sure you can get away with a single-layer layout if what you are experiencing is inductive pickup from mains.  There are loops in your circuit layout that can result in a mains-related induced current.  I might try seeing if rotating the board causes changes in your amplitude.  A ground and possibly a power plane might help with decoupling caps.  If not you will need some shielding.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead Rotating the board does indeed affect the noise amplitude; there was a point with very little noise. Will try a double-sided PCB with the second side serving as ground and report back.

Comment: C7 (100nF) is not doing much @ 400 MHz. You do want to keep your 2V Vcc line free of RF. At this frequency, an efficient bypass capacitor for RF might be in the 300pf - 1000 pf ballpark, with short leads. You have quite a long stretch from Vcc-to-ground, which makes a short-lead bypass difficult.

Comment: @Gomunkul Unfortunately, new capacitors did not help.

Comment: @AltAir Updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry I am not online every day.  I think what you are seeing is inductive pickup from small circuit loops in the layout.  While this may technically be considered EMI, a Faraday shield or similar will not suffice.  50 Hz is too low and will penetrate any of this type of shield.  You must make a magnetic shield.  Ideally, a Mu-metal box or similar surrounding the entire assembly.

Comment: @hidefromkgb, I'm sorry to hear that. The main idea was to not use caps with acoustic effect. If you did use another type of ceramic cap, did it affect the sound signature?

Comment: Is getting interesting. Am curious about your SDR. Its VCO may be interacting with your oscillator, especially if the two modules are too tightly coupled. Your note about orientation is suggesting this. One other thing: your power supply GRN ground connection...try connecting this to BLK (power supply negative) and note any 50 Hz signal.

Comment: @glen_geek Tried receiving a signal from my oscillator on a 5m distance and it doesn\`t differ from receiving in close proximity. Also tried connecting GRN to BLK, to no avail. All sockets in the apartment are grounded.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead Can you please advise me on where to buy such a box? Searched on both Ebay and our local e-shops, but only found various permalloy foils.

Comment: @Gomunkul That\`s quite hard to tell, I\`m afraid: the noise signature varies with every single run, being heavily affected by the placement of the PCB; see @JohnBirckhead\`s comment.

Comment: @hidefromkgb I have always made the enclosures by bending sheets - I don't know if I've ever seen any standard boxes except for transformer cases.  Before you go to all of the effort, find some mild steel and try it.  You could clamshell two shallow steel cookie pans around your part.  If your hum is attenuated, you are on the right track.  Mild steel is not as effective but should make a difference.

Comment: I’m not sure the demod of carrier result is being tracked correctly since raising C4 lowers   the carrier significantly. If tracking ok, then C4 needs to be shielded, but Johanson tubular coaxial variable caps are $$

Comment: And increasing C4 is ultimately counterproductive: your sensor (Cvar) gives more delta-Freq when tank L/C ratio is high. Am wondering if you need a buffer between this oscillator and antenna. Try this: unsolder antenna completely. You may have to couple to SDR a bit tighter. Does that help reduce spurious modulation?

Comment: @glen_geek Yes! After I removed the antenna, the mains noise got decimated! Although it is not gone completely I can\`t hear it anymore, I can only see it on the spectrum. Tested with C₄ = 1 pF.

Comment: @hidefromkgb I will let you decide who I should give the bounty to.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Thank you! The problem has been fully resolved, the bounty should go to glen_geek.

Comment: @hidefromkgb It looks like we found the missing flux capacitor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gomunkul (in comments) & @user287001 may have nailed most of the hum problem:

> It's probably your probe or the antenna that catches the hum from the air because the capacitor is an open circuit for 50Hz.

C6 may be a poor-quality capacitor that varies capacitance with voltage:

- Use a good C0G capacitor here (100 pf is likely too much) or one rated for microwave.
- Terminate the antenna with a resistor-to-ground, to reduce the electric field across C6 induced from nearby 50 Hz appliances, lights.
- Add a buffer stage with nice low S12 between oscillator and antenna.

---

There *is* another possible hum mechanism, somewhat less likely....
This oscillator with antenna can be considered a crude direct-conversion receiver: its oscillations serve as the receiver's local oscillator. With such low-voltage DC bias voltages, this oscillator's active device junctions may have significant capacitance variations with changes in voltage. Where a junction sees both transmitted signal (strong) and received signal (weak), its bias voltage can vary, depending on the phase relationship between the two signals.

Far away, some diode junction(s) may receive some transmitted signal from your oscillator. Where these junctions **are also** turned on & off while rectifying 50 Hz mains, they re-transmit a 50 Hz. modulated signal back to the oscillator via wires or traces. At UHF, even a short wire becomes a coupled antenna element in this 2-element system. The 50 Hz modulated diode may inject a phase change back at the oscillator. It is characteristically full of harmonics, since those 50 Hz modulated diodes switch from on-to-off fairly rapidly. Your spectrum's 50 Hz harmonics seem quite strong. 
DC power supply rectifying diodes are often the source.
LED lighting circuits could be another source.
Your cell-phone shifting frequency also supports this theory.

You might test for this phenomenon with the following (incomplete) circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8B3GL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The half-wave dipole is cut for the oscillator-under-test's UHF frequency. Its diode connects between each 1/4 wave element. A 1kHz function generator could be used to turn the diode on-and-off rather than a 555  1 kHz oscillator. When this "mosquito" circuit is coupled to the transmitter's antenna, a monitoring receiver (AM PM or FM) may detect the 1kHz signal. Moving this "mosquito" circuit away from the oscillator-under-test should  reduce the monitoring receiver's audible output.

An aside: this same coupling mechanism is sometimes present in doppler radar, and motion-detecting theft alarms. In this case, phase changes as the reflecting signal distance varies from the UHF signal oscillator.
You may get more insights by googling "tune-able hum" or tunable hum.

Comment: Woohoo! Adding the output buffer and decreasing C₆ to 2.2 pF eliminated the noise completely. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

You schematic is inaccurate in the real physical model so it won't work as expected in your schematic.

For example your decoupling 0.1uF cap is about 20nH in the 2 leads of 2cm and 1mm thickness (est) and 1cm track length. Meanwhile your resonator uses 33nH , so your supply has poor impedance and as others suggest perhaps 100pF in a small SMD cap is needed.  The overall layout is too big without a ground plane and therefore has a large loop antenna area for radiating and receiving stray electric fields.

I agree most of your hum is due to the large layout >5% of a wavelength for supply, ground and circuit loop path. This makes is prone to radiated noise and conducted ground noise.  Using an RF CM balun or RF CM choke is essential for your DC supply to decouple it from AC grounds in addition to an RF cap preferably a 100pF NPO cap for lowest ESR.

Without a super narrow  IF band Spectrum Analyzer (<100Hz) to examine AM vs FM , it is impossible to tell how much noise is in your SDR and how much is in the Tx.  But either way the hum is mostly in your LCO design and DC power/return paths.  If you had a lab RF gen. , then you can validate your SDR and a good RF SA to validate your noise source.

When we made VCO's in the mid 90's for 928 MHz ISM band for we made custom ceramic hybrids with custom metal lids seam soldered over the hybrid soldered to a GETEK FR4 substrate with another ground plane > 60 dB CNR ( carrier to noise ratio and low phase noise for a 6kHz Tx bandwidth used for automated 2 way meter reading.

- Dielectric constant, substrate loss tangent and shield capacitance all played a role in the design and I recall at the time 603 size 47pF NPO with 2 stage RC LPF were used to reduce supply noise to get down to 10 Ohms then used a design with low supply sensitivity with current sources unlike this one.  Now Murata makes low ESL caps of 100pF or more to cover this spectrum that are wider than long.

### lessons to learn

- How to calculate and measure inductance, ESL and ESR of tracks wires and passive components.
- How to validate RF with a SA to isolate root causes of noise.
- How to discover how critical layout with options for  ground planes , stripline , microstrip and cover shields to minimize interference using waveguide theory, controlled impedances, crosstalk and antenna sensitivity - How to measure  return loss measurement techniques and how to improve spectral purity with higher Q resonators and low Q supply decoupling with CM rejection.
- This is just a start and the expertise is what makes good RF design Engineers worth more than others. ( I don't consider myself one, but I have learned from the best to know. )

### Final words

If you master Ohms Law for RF using calculators for  impedance of tracks, wires and coupling capacitance between stripline, you can understand better how to use a Balun to raise CM impedance then attenuate with shunt loads while controlling the differential impedance.  This applies to 1GHz  PHY networks as well as your Oscillator designs so you can observe similar designs to see these features and apply impedance ratios and Q of resonator to control the resulting SNR.  It's all in the complex impedance ratios  like a 2 dimensional version of Ohm's law with reactive impedance, then it starts to look simpler with antenna aperture effects. (Directional loop antenna)

Comment: I\`ve updated the post and added the spectrum, but I\`m not sure if I made it correctly. Unfortunately, I made the new board before you posted the answer, will try to find some CM chokes and see if they help.

Comment: I can't believe you do not understand antenna aperture effect of signal/wavelength aperture ratio. Why are you looking for baseband 50Hz on the SDR when it is on the modulation. you could examine AC coupled DC or 50Hz IF bandwidth of carrier

Comment: How tight is your Faraday shield? for resistance and slots?

Comment: There must\`ve been a misunderstanding. I did actually examine the 455 kHz IF at a carrier of 480 MHz and then of 514 MHz; the frequency changed after I added the EMI shield. I posted the result in my third question update: there is an IF spectrum from DC to 220 Hz, see the pictures (#1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/188et.png, #2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlxKv.png).

WRT the Faraday shield, it only has 2 slots, which you can see on the picture I also added to the question. The resistance is below my multimeter range (0.1Ω to be precise).

Comment: Ok thanks. The above photos only show white noise with one a few dB lower than the other. So 50Hz hum gone now with ground plane "donut"? What needs to be fixed now?

Comment: It works on my sim http://tinyurl.com/y7jbvh3f  consider decoupling ground currents with CM choke (Ethernet Phy) on output to isolate hum.

Comment: I\`ve ordered the chokes, will test the circuit with them. WRT the noise, it is most likely frequency noise rather than the amplitude one. See the question update.

Answer (score 2):

If smaller coils help, your circuit probably catches magnetic fields. They can be quite strong near transformers or fluorescent lamps.

Your sensor cannot be elsewhere than in your circuit board at 500MHz. I guess it senses acceleration, humidity, some gas or pressure. You probably can put your circuit into a thick soft iron box which short circuits the external magnetic fieds even when having some holes for the needed connection to ouside air. You need a local voltage regulator to keep the AC fields out of the 2VDC operating voltage.

Sync your scope to mains AC and see, is the hum stable in the scope screen. If it's not, your circuit oscillates itself at about 50Hz.

Test also, is your circuit mechanically microphonic. I have made a transmitter which (unwantedly) picked quite weak vibrations.

You wrote "50Hz AC is present only at the antenna output" It's probably your probe or the antenna that catches the hum from the air because the capacitor is an open circuit for 50Hz.

The mains hum+harmonics also can be filtered out from the demodulated signal by  filtering software. The filtering is essential for example in brain or heart tests and cleaning the audio signals.

Test your receiver with another transmitter. Is the receiver itself hum-free.

Answer (score 0):

I understand an oscilloscope is expensive(unless you live in US. I've seen a lot of cheap scopes going to 500 MHz or so on ebay). You should get a signal generator and a milivoltmeter for those frequencies(you might be ok with a SDR for milivolmeter, depending on what you have). From the pictures you attached I suspect the oscillator doesn't work at all. That's not what a sinusoid looks like (be it 400MHz or 50Hz, a sinusoid is a sinusoid). Whatever shape you got there is so ugly you can't even name it. Try to analyze it in two steps: first step, make sure you can amplify a signal in that range. Second step: check what your tuned feedback does in that range. Yes, you need a signal generator for that. You might use the SDR as milivoltmeter/scope, but you do need a signal generator. Had you had hum, it should either 1)be gone on battery power supply or 2)be present even after you remove the battery.

Comment: When you say that the oscillator isn't working, and, "Whatever shape you got there is so ugly you can't even name it", what do you mean? Which figure are you referring to? The images are frequency domain plots, not time domain.